# Referencing (Calling) Web Service within same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, silverlight, asmx

[image]I have created two separate projects, one Web Forms, one Silverlight. 
I have implemented a Web Service in the Web Project that I call through a ServiceReference from Silverlight to pass some values back to the Web Project.

PROBLEM: 
In testing it works 100% if I start my Web Project in one VS instance, and Silverlight Project i another VS instance - Silverlights calls the service and I receive the call in the Web Project,etc, etc.

I have now included the Silverlight project in the same solution as the Web Project and now it is not working - No Error, No Reply from Service, Nothing...

Content of my ServiceReferences.ClientConfig:

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="EnrollServiceSoap" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/EnrollService.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="EnrollServiceSoap"
            contract="EnrollServiceReference.EnrollServiceSoap"
            name="EnrollServiceSoap" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

MY SERVICE IMPLEMENTATION IN WEB PROJECT:

```
namespace XXX
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for EnrollService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class EnrollService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public void UpdateFingerTemplates(string PersonID)
    {
        Person person = SQLData.Persons.getPersonByID(PersonID);
        Person newPerson = SQLData.Persons.getPersonByID(PersonID);
        newPerson.ID_Number = PersonID;

        SQLData.Persons.UpdatePerson(newPerson, person, null);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried enabling the svc logging to find out what is wrong?

Comment: Can you post the config files of your WebForms and Silverlight projects ?

Comment: @Rom Eh, I do not notice anything related to the WebServices in my Web Project (Web.Config)...
Edited the Question with what is in the Silverlight ServiceReferences.ClientConfig

Comment: Is localhost:8080 a reference to your local IIS ? Can you add a capture of your web service deployment configuration ? Your problem may be a conflict between the two openned solutions, which both target the same location.

Comment: @Rom Eh, Sorry I am new to Web Services and may be slow in following you, but below is the Implementation of the WebService (Not sure what you mean by "service deployment configuration") - I am running this through VS and have not deployed anything as yet.
ADDED CODE TO THE QUESTION

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your porject configuration ? Right click on your web project, the select properties, and navigate to the Web tab.

Comment: @Rom Eh, Screenshot Added.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: @John Saunders, Thank you - I am aware of this, and switch to asmx out of pure frustration, but will switch back to WCF... As long as I can solve my issue.

Comment: @silvermind, I have changed my solution back to WCF, and implemented the logging.
If I run my projects from two separate VS instances it creates the log file whn the service is called, and only contains "information items".
If I however run the solution containing both projects, launching the Silverlight component from my Web Project, no log file is created - Telling me that SL is not calling the service...???

Comment: In your solution with the two projects, can you try to select temporarely the Visual Studio Development Server, wihtout changing any parameter ? Can ou tell me if it works ?

Comment: Change the portnumber of your service reference (if you have it dynamic set it to manual, change and save it and set it back to dynamic and save again). Readd the service reference with the discover button and make sure you select the one with your assigned port number. See if that works.

Comment: @Silvermind and RomEh, I have tried both your suggestions separately, but no luck.

Comment: Does it freeze on the call? Or does it just run over and not return anything?

Comment: @Silvermind Just runs over, no return, no error, nadda

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but can you right click your .svc and show in browser? Than view the wsdl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved...
I was being a Dumb@ss, by calling the WCF Service from BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress (Which I did not expect to be a problem (If someone cares tocomment why), and stupidly neglected to mention in the post)
Moving the call to the WCF Service to BackgroundWorker.ProcessCompleted solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Map your service project to local IIS for debug. and add reference of service from IIS path it should work in one solution itself..
Right Click on WCF project>>Properties>>Web>>Choose Local IIS web server>> enter Project URL of an IIS application path

Answer (score -1):

in your silver Light project Remove the old service reference first ,then 
Project Menu ===> Add Service Reference ====> Advanced ... ====> Add Web Reference

then choose web services in this solution Link.

Comment: -1: "Add Web Reference" is part of the legacy ASMX technology, which should not be used for new development.